# Can I get a list of all emails by email ID in Pardot?

Tags: pardot

I'm using the Pardot API version 3, and need to collect a list of emails. On [this doc](http://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-3/emails/) the only query option I see requires an email ID.

If I want to get, for example, the email name for each email, will I have to make a separate API call for each email by ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get IDs
In Pardot...

1. Marketing -> Emails -> Sent
2. Select view "All Sent List Emails"
3. On the right click "Tools", CSV Export
4. You will receive a file of your sent List Emails with email ID.

Yes, you will have to make a separate API call for each ID. How are you planning to do this? If you're okay with Python, I recommend the PyPardot package (I maintain version 4)